# Read XML file and write to a php array/file

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need to update the country list of my website and I want to automate the process. Country list can be found here
http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes...code_lists.htm // Edit : Can't find the good link...

I tried it this way –
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parser_expat.asp (PHP XML Expat Parser)
However, this didn't seem to work well as I was confused where to actually 'get' the data and print it to my own array for later use.

Now I want to try it using [XML DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php).

Just want to check with everyone, if I had a simple XML file to read, that contained a country code and country name as follows:

```
<Entry> 
<Country_name>AFGHANISTAN</Country_name>
<Code_element>AF</Code_element>
</Entry>
```

I want to read this file (DOM method), and then feed the data into a separate file/array of mine that will be accessed by my website. What PHP xml functions would YOU use/recommend to do this simple task?

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
    $dom = new DOMDOcument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $res = $xpath->query("/CODE");
$allres = array();
foreach($res as $node){
        $result = array();
$result['country'] = ($node->getElementsByTagName("Country_name")->item(0)->nodeValue);
$result['code'] = ($node->getElementsByTagName("Code_element")->item(0)->nodeValue);
$allres[] = $res
}
```

in the end `$allres` array would contain all your country codes and names