# Load XML Data To a Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to be able to take the data from within an XML file and insert it into my database table.

The XML file I'm using is structured like this:

```
<STORY>
<ID>1</ID>
<TITLE>ABCD</TITLE>
<STORYMAIN>ABCDEFGH</STORYMAIN>
</STORY>
```

I have tried using the following code but it fails.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'equitymarketnews/$zname' INTO TABLE `equitymarketnews` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES STARTING BY '<row>' TERMINATED BY '</row>'
```

Comment: Are you wanting to save the xml file in the database or insert the data from the xml into a table in the database?

Comment: i want to save data from xml file to databse

Comment: for this first extract the xml file and then insert into database..

Comment: Do you want to maintain the xml syntax though? I.e. all of XML content in a single column or for each item in xml save to a specific column (xml storymain --> sqlTableForXML.storymain)

Comment: can you please give me a code ?

Comment: Give you code for which method?

Comment: for insertion xml data to table

Comment: In that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101947/read-xml-file-and-write-to-a-php-array-file should get you started - from there you can easily push the php array items into a mysql insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.5 then you can LOAD XML options available, you need to map rows(`<STORY>`) using `ROWS IDENTIFIED BY` clause. Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).
The other option is, you can process the XML data in PHP using options like simple XML or convert it to PHP array(Google for how to), and then use simple insert commands to insert it into DB.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) statement, not LOAD DATA INFILE.

Note, LOAD XML was added in MySQL 5.5.